# Batch file to copy files from a folder which contain values (anywhere in the filename) read from LIST.TXT?

Tags: batch-file, path

This seems an easy task, but I cannot seem to work it out.

I have a LIST.TXT file with as follows:

```
123456
555789
8888988898
12125
```

I have a large volume of files with those numbers at the start of their file names:

```
123456_wedding1.jpg
123456_wedding2.doc
123456_wedding3.xls
555789_henrysales_horse.jpg
555789_goodtimes.mov
8888988898_33.avi
12125_some long description here.asx
12125_shor desc.asx
12125_shor desc2.xlsx
```

I declare vairables: theList, theSource & theDestination and I simply want to copy the files to theDestination folder (I don't even need subfolders).

Following is the code I attempted to adapt from other kind folk:

```
REM @ECHO OFF

REM **************************************************

REM Adjust location of list
SET "theList=C:\2. List\List.txt"

REM Source dir
SET "theSource=C:\2. Files\"

REM Target dir
SET "theDestination=C:\2. Found\"

REM **************************************************

FOR /F "tokens=1,* delims=|" %%A IN (%theList%) DO (
    ECHO.
    ECHO %%A - %%B
    CALL :copy "%%A - %%B"
)   

ECHO.
ECHO Done^!
PAUSE
EXIT

:copy
FOR /R "%theSource%" %%F IN (*) DO (
    ECHO "%%~nF" | FINDSTR /C:%1 >nul && COPY "%%~fF" "%theDestination%\%%~nxF" && EXIT /B
)

pause 
EXIT /B
```

However, I am still getting this error:

> The system cannot find the file C:\2..

It seems to be something to do with spaces in the files or folders, but I can't nut it out.

**Your would be assistance greatly appreciated**

Comment: There is an [edit] link below your post (and a delete link) :) I've fixed it for you ...

Comment: Your List.txt file seems to have only one number per line, but you try to parse two delimited by a verticval bar? Passing this to the :copy subroutine with a trailing space dash space won't find any correspondent file as they start with number underscore.

Answer (score 1):

Would PowerShell be an option for this?  This seems like a better tool for the job and would certainly make it simpler.  For example, the bones of the solution could be:

```
$theList        = "C:\2. List\List.txt"
$theSource      = "C:\2. Files\"
$theDestination = "C:\2. Found\"
$toCheck        = gc $theList  

Get-ChildItem $theSource | Foreach-Object{        
    if($toCheck -match $_.BaseName)
    {
       write-host "matches in list file $($theList):" $_.FullName
       copy-item $_.FullName -destination $theDestination
    } 
}
```

This will just copy the file.  If you want to move it consider using move-item.

If you really want sub-strings of the base file name to match entries in the list file, a verbose way, to make it readable and for you to modify or extend, the following could help:

```
$theList        = "C:\2. List\List.txt"
$theSource      = "C:\2. Files\"
$theDestination = "C:\2. Found\"
$toCheck        = gc $theList  

function inArrayasSub([string]$stringToCheck)
{
    write-host "`tchecking: '$($stringToCheck)' exists (substring) in file " $theList 

    foreach ($entry in $toCheck)
    {
       if ($stringToCheck -match $entry)
       {
           write-host "`tExists based on entry: $entry"
           return $true 
       }
    }
    return $false
}

Get-ChildItem $theSource | Foreach-Object{

    write-host "Testing file basename: "$_.BaseName

    if (inArrayasSub $_.BaseName)    
    {
       write-host $_.BaseName "matches in list file $($theList):" $_.FullName
       copy-item $_.FullName -destination $theDestination
    } 
    write-host "======================"
}
```

Comment: Thank you @HelpingHand! **Would PowerShell be an option for this?** I am not averse to PowerShell (especially since I've now worked out how to launch them from a bat file) - thank you, I will give that a go. **a verbose way .. the following could help** I will also look at this option. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

Batch file which:

- splits all files from the source at the underscore
- uses findstr /G: to compare the splitted number with theList
- if the number is present copy else echo message

Untested:

```
:: Q:\Test\2019\01\06\SU_1390824.cmd
@ECHO OFF

:: Adjust location of list
Set "theList=C:\2. List\List.txt"
:: Source dir
Set "theSource=C:\2. Files\"
:: Target dir
Set "theDestination=C:\2. Found"

For /R "%theSource%" %%A IN (*) DO For /F "delims=_" %%B in ("%%~nA") DO ( 
    ECHO:%%B|FINDSTR /XG:"%theList%" >nul 2>&1 && (
        COPY "%%~fA" "%theDestination%\%%~nxA"
    )||(
        Echo Not in theList: %%B , %%A
    )
)
Echo Done^!
Pause 
Exit /B
```

Comment: thany you so much for your help - I'll try this out.